# How to remove a row from an Oracle cursor but not the database table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a FOR LOOP cursor and while looping through it I need to delete some of the rows from the cursor but not from the database table. Is that possible to do?

What I am trying to accomplish is to be left with only those rows in the cursor my code did not process by removing each processed row that met certain criteria

Comment: Why not to put unprocessed rows (PK, reference to it, whatever) into a separate collection and use it afterwards?

Comment: but how would I determine which rows were unprocessed if my code never gets to them?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that demonstrates the problem; help us to help you by giving an example (that compiles) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @CodingDuchess, just read from the cursor till the end and add each row into the collection. Another approach could be - sort the data so that 'processable' recrords go first. In this case once you encounter an 'unprocessable' record, you can process the rest of the rows using a different algorithm.

Comment: @CodingDuchess, anyway, answering your question - no, you can not modify a cursor.

Comment: "What I am trying to accomplish is to be left with only those rows in the cursor my code did not process by removing each processed row that met certain criteria" You cannot read from a cursor twice - what do you mean by being "left with only those rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulk collect the cursor rows into a collection. Then as each row in processed delete it from the collection. What's left will be the rows not originally processed. The following provides a skeleton for the process needed:

```
declare
   cursor c_cursor
   is
      select ... ;

   type c_cursor_t is table of c_cursor%rowtype;
   l_cursor_data   c_cursor_t; 

   l_cursor_indx   integer;
begin
   open  c_cursor;
   fetch c_cursor
    bulk collect 
    into l_cursor_data;
   close c_cursor; 

   l_cursor_indx := l_cursor_data.first;       -- set collection index to 1st value
   while l_cursor_indx is not null
   loop
      if <row should be processed>             -- determine which rows to process
      then 
          <process_row>;                        -- and process them
          l_cursor_data.delete(l_cursor_indx);  -- then delete processed rows
      end if ; 

      l_cursor_indx := l_cursor_data.next(l_cursor_indx); -- set collection index to next row or null if no morw rows. 
   end loop; 

   --- Handle anything left in l_cursor_data collection as they have not been processed.
   --- THE SAME LOOP STRUCTURE AN BE USED FOR THE COLLECTION IF NEEDED. 
end ;
```

Of course as @MT0 it would be much easier to eliminate those that will not be processed from the query to begin with. Just retrieve the rows you want to process is always the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a cursor while you are reading it; if you want to exclude rows then you will need to do it when you are generating the cursor.

Use the `WHERE` clause to exclude the rows from the cursor:

```sql
DECLARE
  OPEN cursor_name FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  primary_key_column NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3 ); -- criteria to exclude.
BEGIN
  -- process cursor with excluded rows.
END;
/
```

Comment: @CodingDuchess that is not a constructive statement as it doesn't give us any hint as to why it won't work or what you are trying to achieve. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58503349/edit) your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve, preferably with a concrete example.

Comment: it will not work because my cursor needs to retrieve all data, then a lot of different types of processing done to every row, based on multiple conditions. Then I need to capture only those rows that were not touched. I was thinking on copying all the rows I process into a collection and then, once done with processing, loop through the cursor and check which rows are not in that collection to determine untouched rows

Comment: @CodingDuchess you appear to have a solution (the one you've just described); you can write that up as a self-answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Load a collection with the results from your query, making sure the collection contains a 'processed' flag that is initialized to False.  Then loop through the collection, processing as you need to.  Flip the flag to True when done.

Then you could loop through the collection again where the processed_flag is False to get your untouched rows.